# Vue 3 pars json from subase to ref is this correct way?

Tags: vuejs3, supabase

This is the code i use. The issue i have is that when i change  {{ jsondata }} to  {{ jsondata.title }} it will work when using hot reload but as soon as i refresh the page i get a read properties of undefined (reading 'title') error. I tried a couple of things. I used onbeforemount which also seem to half fix it. It shows now the title name but still the undefined error. So then i tried `const jsondata = ref({});` adding the {}. This seems to work. Is this the correct way to fix this? Or should i handle this different since i get data async?

```
 <template>
  <main class="flex-1">
    <div class="py-16">
      <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-18">
        <h1 class="text-2xl font-semibold text-gray-900">Playground</h1>
      </div>

      <!-- Replace with your content -->
      {{ jsondata }}

      <div class="py-4">
        <div class="h-96 rounded-lg border-4 border-dashed border-gray-200" />
      </div>
      <!-- /End replace -->
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

    <script setup>
      import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
      import { supabase } from "@/libary/supabaseClient";
      const jsondata = ref();
      async function getJson() {
        const { data } = await supabase.from("books").select("*").limit(1).single();
        jsondata.value = data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
      }
    
      onMounted(() => {
        getJson();
      });
    </script>
    the json
    { "id": 1, "title": "The Poky Little Puppy", "author": "Janette Sebring Lowrey", "metadata": { "ages": [ 3, 6 ], "price": 5.95, "description": "Puppy is slower than other, bigger animals." } }
```

Comment: the template is rendered synchronously so any data you display on the UI must exist the moment the component is created/rendered.  If not, like with async data, you get an undefined error.  To prevent it you can use `v-if` to conditionally render data so it's only rendered once it exists. The other option is to provide an initial default value, e.g. `jsondata = ref({title: ''})`

Comment: is adding {} in the ref also fine? I can't find a lot of info about this

Comment: the ref wraps whatever initial value you want to give the variable.  `ref({})` is just saying you want `jsondata` to have an initial value of "empty object".  If you don't try displaying any properties of that empty object on component creation then it will work just fine.  If you wanted to display `jsondata.title` however you'd need to either use `v-if` or give an initial value such as `ref({title: ''})`

Comment: Thanks it looks like {} is also working when wanting to display the title.